# Doesn't GCC recognize the function "read"?

Tags: c, gcc

I was solving the pwnable.kr's fd problem and wondered how does the fd.c code works.
So I copied the c code and I put it on GCC to see how it works. And it has an error says: "implicit declaration of function ‘read’; did you mean ‘fread’?" Does GCC not recognize the Read function on C?

The code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char buf[32];
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]){
        if(argc<2){
                printf("pass argv[1] a number\n");
                return 0;
        }
        int fd = atoi( argv[1] ) - 0x1234;
        int len = 0;
        len = read(fd, buf, 32);
        if(!strcmp("LETMEWIN\n", buf)){
                printf("good job :)\n");
                system("/bin/cat flag");
                exit(0);
        }
        printf("learn about Linux file IO\n");
        return 0;

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Where do you think `read` has been defined?

Comment: @ScottHunter ah i got it!!! i didn't let her know where the file is!!! then I might also copy the other files from that server, right?

Comment: you can't just throw a number (as file descriptor) at I/O functions. Even if it would compile, it would crash. If you issue an `open()` call, it will return a valid fd if the operation was successful. First after opening the file, you can read or write it. After using the file it is a good habit to close it again.

Comment: Actually file descriptors **are** integers. My guess is that this snippet of code is an exercise that aims to teach you a thing or two about file descriptors

Comment: @Ronald Thanks a lot!!!! i joined this site in order to ask this and you guys are so soooooo gentle!!! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

From the man page (`man 2 read`) :

> NAME
>
> read - read from a file descriptor
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> #include <unistd.h>
>
> ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);

You must include `unistd.h` and the warning will go away.

Comment: But that does not mean that using a `fd` that was not opened by your program will work.

Comment: @Gerhardh this is just an exercise to showcase the fact that Linux will automatically open 3 file descriptors (stdin, stdout, stderr) for you, even if you don't explicitly call open in your code

Comment: True, but except for stdin/our/err you will have to open it yourself

Comment: @Gerhardh Well, you are right. It really can't open the file, but it works for 'if' and it really recognizes all the command! Thank you